# Mongodb not responding for any queries

Tags: mongodb

I have tried to copy a collection to another collection.The collection had around 15 million documents. Since it took long time I killed the session . Now when I connect the database none of the queries is responding. Not sure what happened. Any idea?

sample ...

```
{  
 "desc":"conn1188",
 "threadId":"0x1fbbeb60",
 "connectionId":1188,
 "opid":95159403,
 "active":false,
 "op":"query",
 "ns":"local.oplog.rs",
 "query":{  

 },
 "client":"10.63.24.147:49472",
 "numYields":0,
 "locks":{  
    "Global":"r"
 },
 "waitingForLock":true,
 "lockStats":{  
    "Global":{  
       "acquireCount":{  
          "r":NumberLong(1)
       },
       "acquireWaitCount":{  
          "r":NumberLong(1)
       },
       "timeAcquiringMicros":{  
          "r":NumberLong("1878081878439")
       }
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: Run [`db.currentOp()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/) and look at what is happening.

Comment: It results in a huge list ..pasted sample in the original post..There are almost 300 entries as above sample